# Create "custom typeid" for many types AND cache their sizeof()

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof, typeid

There are many type of elements `E0,E1,...`, all of them derived from `Element`.

```
class Element{  public: int id=0; } //"Element" can be edited
class E0: public Element{ ... }
class E1: public Element{ ... }
...
class E999: public Element{ ... }
```

How to cache `sizeof()` for `E0,E1,...`?
It has to return the correct value [#2] later by "custom typeid" [#1].

```
class CCollection{
    template<class EX> EX* create(){ //(Edit)
        //all EX* is created by this function
    }
    /** user only pass EX*, never pass Element* */  (Edit)
    int toId(Element* element){//[#1] should replaced by template?
          //....... return id, e.g. 0 for E0, 1 for E2, 2 for E1, ...  
          // can be in any order, but must unique and packed ........ 
    }
    int sizeOf(int id){//[#2]
        //....... return size of EX
        // must consistent with toId() ,
        // e.g. sizeof(E0) for 0, sizeof(E2) for 1, sizeof(E1) for 2 ........ 
    }
    //....... other fields / functions, if necessary ............


}
```

How to implement this?

### **Requirement:**

1. Manually assign id-integer of `E0,E1,E2,...` is not allowed, because of low maintainability.
2. User doesn't have to "register" `E0,E1,E2,...` to `CCollection` manually.
   When new type of Element, e.g. E1000, no modification have to be done.
   ..... i.e.  `CCollection` should be "just work" for E1000.
3. Highest performance, e.g. :-

   - Virtual calling should be avoided, except totally unavoidable.
   - Use `constexpr` if possible.
   - Static variable inside a function is not good.
4. Don't modify code of `E0,E1,E2,...`

### Flexibility in design

5. If `CCollection`'s functions are never called for a certain `E-X`,
   the management for `E-X` can be omitted (up to you).
6. There is only 1 CCollection instance.

**clue1:** Template seems to be the most promising path, but I am not sure.

**clue2:** (Edit) This snippet I have planed may help :-

```
template<class EX> int toId(EX* element){//[#1] 
    // register something?
}
```

As you can guess, the real problem is far bigger than this,
but this is the only one missing jigsaw of my whole puzzle.

Although I wish for code, just a guide is really appreciated.

Comment: are the types really called `Exxx` or are these just demo names?

Comment: Sure!  They are demo names.

Comment: could `Element` become a template? i.e. this would allow `class E0: public Element<E0>{ ... }`

Comment: No, it violates 4 (modify source code of E-X), sorry.  I have a lot of E, so I want to keep them as clean as possible.

Comment: As neither `Element` or `CCollection` know concrete type `E1`, .., `E999`, I don't see how to have information from their type in those classes.

Comment: @javaLover: CRTP with `class E0 : public ElementCRTP<E0> {}` seems clean and would allow to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank, you have a point.   I edited the question (I did not explain it clear enough), #1 always receive E-X*, never receive Element*.  So template may help.

Comment: From your last edit, do you mean that user has to call `CCollection::toId` before `CCollection::sizeOf` (and potentially with concrete type) and so might serve as registration?

Comment: @Jarod42  I don't think so, but there is a way .... all EX are created by CCollection, so I can force that  with a little performance penalty.  ( question edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add an intermediate class between `Element` and each `EX`, here is a possible solution (with a minimal, working example):

```
#include<cstddef>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>

struct Element {
    static std::size_t counter;
};

std::size_t Element::counter = 0;

template<typename>
struct ElementType: Element {
    static const int type;
};

template<typename T>
const int ElementType<T>::type = Element::counter++;

struct E0: ElementType<E0> {};
struct E1: ElementType<E1> { int i; };
struct E2: ElementType<E2> {};

class CCollection {
    void ensure(std::size_t type) {
        if(!(type < sizes.size())) {
            sizes.resize(type+1, 0);
        }
    }

    template<typename EX>
    void ensure() {
        ensure(EX::type);
        sizes[EX::type] = sizeof(EX);
    }

public:
    template<class EX>
    std::shared_ptr<EX> create() {
        ensure<EX>();
        return std::make_shared<EX>();
    }

    template<typename EX>
    std::size_t toId() {
        ensure<EX>();
        return EX::type;
    }

    std::size_t sizeOf(std::size_t type) {
        ensure(type);
        return sizes[type];
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::size_t> sizes;
};

int main() {
    CCollection coll;
    assert(coll.toId<E0>() != coll.toId<E1>());
    assert(coll.toId<E0>() != coll.toId<E2>());
    assert(coll.toId<E1>() != coll.toId<E2>());
    assert(coll.sizeOf(0) == sizeof(E0));
    assert(coll.sizeOf(1) == sizeof(E1));
    assert(coll.sizeOf(2) == sizeof(E2));
    assert(coll.sizeOf(0) != coll.sizeOf(1));
    // ...
}
```

The problem in the code in the example arises if one tries to create instances of `EX` without using `create`.
Anyway:

- You said it should never happen.
- You can enforce the use of that function.
- The `CCollection` class is designed so as it returns 0 from `sizeOf` if you do that.

That said, it can serve as a base for a more elaborated production code at least.

Comment: Thank (late accept).  Six months later, I have enough knowledge to fully understand it.  This is a great answer.  I tested, it is very fast.

Answer (score 2):

I think following doesn't break any of your rules:

```
struct CCollection
{
    template <typename T>
    std::size_t toId() {
        auto it = info.find(typeid(T));
        if (it == info.end()) {
            it = info.insert({typeid(T), {count++, sizeof(T)}}).first;
        }
        return it->second.id;   
    }

    std::size_t sizeOf(const Base& base) const {
        const auto& data = info.at(typeid(base));
        return data.size;   
    }

    std::size_t count = 0;
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, Data> info;
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/28xFOy)

Comment: +1  Thank, but std::unordered_map and typeid is too slow, isn't it?  If you can avoid that, I will be greatly appreciated.  : )

Comment: @javaLover `too slow` compared with what?

Comment: @m.s. I compared it will a few "indirection" + a few arithmetic operation.   It looks like the value can be known at compile time, so I wish it could be cheaper.

Comment: Now you have an factory method, you may store result directly in `Base`, but still get the map for that method. Now you have idea to customize for your needs.

Comment: @javaLover : the problem with your "at compile time" idea is that it breaks in the presence of separate compilation. There's in general no reliable way to enforce that all instantiations of `CCollection::create<EX>` exist in a single Translation Unit. This right away means that `toId(Element*)` must rely on a datastructure created at runtime. An `unordered_map` has `O(1)` lookup, which makes it a logical choice for that runtime datastructure.