# minimum instantiate class object, when query getInstance<T>(), based on inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, singleton

User of my library will ask for an instance of any class via `getInstance<T>()`.

Among all classes `{T1,T2,T3,...,Tn}` that user asks (appearance of calling `getInstance<T>()`) in a certain program, if there is a pair of `(i,j)` and `Ti` derived from `Tj`, I will create only the bigger one, e.g. `Ti`.

Here is an example.
Assume that user's code code ask me to create these classes:-

- Physic
- Rigid
- Constraint
- Graphic

  and their inheritance is as followed:-

*(The above four classes are marked with yellow in the diagram.)*

[image]

My code will create **minimum** amount of class instances that cover the whole tree.
In this case, the best solution are **3** : `Rigid`, `Constraint`, `Graphic`.
Roughly speaking, the three arrows *pass* all classes in the tree.

[image]

In this case, there will be 2 instances of `Physic`, but I don't care.  (Thank Christian Hackl)

More specifically, `getInstance<Physic>()` can return any of them.
The underlying type can be `Rigid*` or `Constraint*` - both are OK.

If there are many **minimum** solutions, any one of them are OK.

Here is what I dream :-

```
//..... some list to cache std::function .... ?
template<class T> T* getInstance(){
    //return new T()  ? 
}
class B{};
class C{};
class D : public B{};
int main(){
    //..... allow to insert some code here ...... (a little less preferable)
    B* b=getInstance<B>();   //return B*  (implicitly cast D*->B*)
    C* c=getInstance<C>();   //return C*
    D* d=getInstance<D>();   //return D* 
    assert( static_cast<D*>(b) == d );
    delete d;    delete c;
    //no memory leak
}
```

How to do it?
This is closest question : [Create "custom typeid" for many types AND cache their sizeof()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075804)

I feel that it is possible : I have to cache the type by using :-

- lambda without capture / `std::function` -> keep it in a list
- The cache function call `std::is_base_of`.
- Then, I have to recognize all leaf-nodes in some ways.
- Amount of classes that have to be instantiated = amount of leaf-nodes.

However, it is far from a concrete idea.

I want to create a very-sophisticated singleton manager for my libraries + educational purpose.
I know it is quite not a good practice,  but I believe the solution will enlighten me in C++ area.
 <sub>Just in case it is not so obvious - this is not a homework / interview.</sub>

Comment: If `Rigid` and `Constraint` both inherit from `Physic`, then `Physic` is not a Singleton. Even if `Physic` is abstract, two subobjects of it must exist within `Rigid` and `Constraint`. The same contradiction applies to `Core`. Generally, once you feel the need to inherit from a supposed Singleton class, the class design has proven to be incorrect.

Comment: @Christian Hackl  Thank.  It is useful, especially the last statement.    I will edit the question to clarify it a little more (even though, you point is still valid).  .....  It is ok for me to have many of those instance (`Core`/`Physic`).   All classes in the tree contains a lot of functions but have very little field/data.

Answer (score 1):

You mainly need a type traits that, given a type and a list of type, return a sort of top derived type from the list.

Not really elegant (I'll try to semplify it) but the following code should give you an example

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct core {};
struct physic     : public core {};
struct rigid      : public physic {};
struct constraint : public physic {};
struct graphic    : public core {};

template <typename ... Ts>
struct contTypes
 { };

template <typename T0, typename T1>
struct isStrictBase
 { static constexpr bool value =
         (false == std::is_same<T0, T1>::value)
      && (true == std::is_base_of<T0, T1>::value); };

template <bool, typename...>
struct chooseT;

template <typename, typename, typename>
struct getTopTypeH;

template <typename C0, typename T, typename T0, typename C1>
struct chooseT<true, C0, T, T0, C1>
 { using type = typename getTopTypeH<C0, T0, C0>::type; };

template <typename C0, typename T, typename T0, typename C1>
struct chooseT<false, C0, T, T0, C1>
 { using type = typename getTopTypeH<C0, T, C1>::type; };

template <typename, typename, typename>
struct getTopTypeH;

template <template <typename ...> class Ct, typename ... Ts0, typename T>
struct getTopTypeH<Ct<Ts0...>, T, Ct<>>
 { using type = T; };

template <template <typename ...> class Ct, typename ... Ts0,
          typename T, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct getTopTypeH<Ct<Ts0...>, T, Ct<T0, Ts...>>
 {
   using type = typename chooseT<isStrictBase<T, T0>::value,
                                 Ct<Ts0...>, T, T0, Ct<Ts...>>::type;
 };

template <typename T, typename CT>
struct getTopType
 { using type = typename getTopTypeH<CT, T, CT>::type; };


template <typename T>
struct staticWrapper
 {
   static T * getPnt ()
    {
      static T st{};

      return & st;
    }
 };

using cT = contTypes<core, physic, rigid, constraint, graphic>;

template <typename T>
T * getInstance ()
 { return staticWrapper<typename getTopType<T, cT>::type>::getPnt(); }

int main ()
 {
   auto p0 = getInstance<core>();
   auto p1 = getInstance<physic>();
   auto p2 = getInstance<rigid>();
   auto p3 = getInstance<constraint>();
   auto p4 = getInstance<graphic>();

   assert( p0 == p1 );
   assert( p0 == p2 );

   std::cout << "assert passed" << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for being not clear.  `getInstance<T>()` always return `T*` in term of syntax, but the underlying type (true type) of the return pointer  `T*` can be something more specific e.g. can be `T2*` (if `T2` is derived from `T`).   ..... Agree, this is not an important  part of the question.   ..... I am learning you code, thank!

Comment: @javaLover - I see... well... you can simply return `T *` but loosing the `static_assert` check

Comment: After some testing, this solution creates 5 instances : 3 `rigid` + 1 `constraint` + 1 `graphic`.   The best solution is 3 instance though (the green arrow).  Hmm, I think I will find a way to modify/improve it.   As an example/clue, it is great. ... hmm ...

Comment: @javaLore - observe that the type of the istances created is strictly dependant from the order of the types in the `using ct` definition; changing the order ot types in `contTypes` you can change the types of the istances created

Comment: @javaLover - A word about the minimum number of classes: if I understand your requirements, this number is the number of leaves in the tree of types. My example should find a minimum solution indipendetely from the order of types in definition of `using ct` (or maybe I don't understand your requirements)

Comment: In your full demo, where it calls 5 `getInstance()`, up-to-5 `new` are also called currently.   In my requirements, only 3 `new` should be called.  A possible solution is just `new` only `rigid()/constraint()/graphic()`.   The `getInstance<core>()` can return one of those 3 instances (i.e. share pointer with those), and `getInstance<physic>()` should return one of the same instance as `new rigid()/constraint()` (shared).  ......  In my question, I show `assert( static_cast<D*>(b) == d );` and `no leak`  to emphasize that `b` & `d` are actually the same instance.  (Sorry if it is unclear. )

Comment: @javaLover - not sure to understand... do you want a `getIstance()` that, given a template type, return ever the same object? I mean: `assert( getIntance<core>() == getInstance<core>())`?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same (should equal).  Oh, I got where it is unclear.  :(

Comment: @javaLover - I see... let me think a little and a I try to correct my solution.

Comment: If you can also  remove the manual list `contTypes<core, physic, rigid, constraint, graphic>;`, it would be wonderful. ......  If you can, but it takes too much time from you, just tell me e.g. "It is possible, but I will give it as your homework".  It would be still great.  ...... Furthermore, compilable code is actually not required, just a guide is really appreciated.

Comment: @javaLover - I've added a static wrapper to return, given a type, even the same pointer value (of a static wrapped instance); and, no, I don't know how to avoid the manual list of `contTypes`